# Spaces are replaced with colons when transporting the environment variables into WSL because of using OpenFoam

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using windows-subsystem-for-Linux, and I choose Ubuntu. But I can't call the program installed on the Windows OS, so I check the environment variable list in WSL, it seems that the spaces are replaced with colons when transporting the environment variables into WSL.
Considering that in WSL, the environment variables list is a colon-delimited list. In Win32, it is a semicolon-delimited list. 
I think this the reason why I can't call the program installed on the windows OS. So I checked another laptop, this phenomenon doesn't exist and everything works fine.

My question is:

1. Why does this problem happen?
2. How could I fix it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have several problems in here.

1. Executing a windows binary program from a WSL Linux Shell.
   You're executing Windows, so why don't you run your program from Windows CMD, a .BAT file, or Powershell?.

In any case, make sure that you have enabled this in /etc/wsl.conf

```
[interop]
enabled=True
```

Please note: This option is available in Insider Build 17713 and later.

2. Why the problem with the path, transforming spaces to : ?
   I don't know. In Linux spaces in the path are represented by:

```
\
```

(bar and a space, inside quotes, or space if not using quotes)

So I think you need to replace your PATH by what you have by replacing:
**d/ProgramFiles/VS_Code/Microsoft:VS:Code/bin**
by:
**d/ProgramFiles/VS_Code/Microsoft\ VS\ Code/bin**

Please check:
/etc/wsl.conf

You should have:

```
[interop]
appendWindowsPath=True
```

Please, check **options** in **[automount]** section.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#configure-per-distro-launch-settings-with-wslconf

If you need to patch your PATH every time you can do a script like fixpath.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | sed "s/Microsoft:VS:Code/Microsoft\ VS\ Code/")
export PATH
```

Then you run:

```
source ./fixpath.sh
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I found that this is because I am using OpenFoam, and when the PATH env of OpenFoam takes effect, it rebuilds the PATH environment variable, the corresponding setting in ~/.bashrc file is:
`source /opt/openfoam8/etc/bashrc`

As shown in the following screenshot, OpenFoam would rebuild the $PATH environment variable, with colon and space as the delimiter.
[image]

Comment: Well done @Jack! :)